# Pseudo-random algorithm for selecting semi-random item in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, indexing

I have a simple array (or set if you prefer) of integers, let's call it X. I also have another array W that stores the "weight" of elements in array X. The "weight" indicates how likely n-th element should be selected. Now I need a method (algorithm) to (pseudo) randomly select one element from array/set X according to its "weight" defined in array W.

For example, if my W looks like this:
    W[0] = 2;
    W[1] = 4;
    W[2] = 6;

that means probability of selecting N-th item from array X is:
    X[0] = 16.6%
    X[1] = 33.3%
    X[2] = 50%

so method get_pseudorandom_item(X) should return 2-nd item around half of all times.

Any ideas or suggestions how to implement this (in any programming language) are much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Generate an array **P** with the partial sums of the weights, i.e.

   (**P**<sub>0</sub> = **W**<sub>0</sub>), (**P**<sub>1</sub> = **W**<sub>0</sub> + **W**<sub>1</sub>), ..., (**P**<sub>*n*</sub> = **W**<sub>0</sub> + **W**<sub>1</sub> + ... + **W**<sub>*n*</sub>)

   (you can do that within **W**, actually, if you don't need the weights afterwards).
2. Generate a random number *r* in [0, **P**<sub>*n*</sub>) where **P**<sub>*n*</sub> denotes the last such sum (i.e. the sum of *all* weights).
3. Find the index *k* of the *smallest* (first) partial sum *larger* than the number you generated:

   **P**<sub>*k*</sub> > *r*  ∧  ∀ *a* < *k*: **P**<sub>*a*</sub> < *r*
4. Use that index to select your actual element: **X**<sub>*k*</sub>

Comment: If speed is important, you can use binary search in step 3, since the array is nondecreasing and thus sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the numbers in `X[]` add up to 1.0. So `X[2]` would be `0.5000`.

You pick your number and add until you 'run out of chance'.

Here's a Java example:

```java
double rand = random.nextDouble();
double sofar = 0.0;

for(int i = 0; i < X.length; x++) {
    if(sofar + X[i] > rand) return W[i];
    sofar += X[i];
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Numbers add up to less than 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

For each object type x[i] Where y is it's weight. Add y elements in an array of type x[i].

Then select from this array randomly.

Taking your example you would have 2 W[0], 4 W[1] and 6 W[2] in the collection from which you randomly pick an item which will be of type 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: This is nice if you have lots of space (memory) and will be using the weights table repeatedly.  In this solution, you don't have to search a weights table.

Comment: Agreed, it's not the most efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is not a very pretty solution, but I will share it anyways!

You could create another array (say with 100 integers).
Each integer would represent the index in **W**.
Based upon the percentage given, you can fill that array with the integers.

So if you have X[0] = 25% X[1] = 25% X[2] = 50%
The array would have 25 1's, 25 2's and 50 3's

Then you could select a pseudo-random index of that array and use the returned index to retrieve the object in **W**.

Like I said, it's ugly, but it would work :)